# How to show the text from edit text input layout to list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I am trying to get a text from edit text input layout and show the text on list view when click next edit text drop down button. Like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Edittext.getText.ToString()` will give you the entered text in `editText`.

And for drop down you should use Spinner.